# BIRT : Total 500 records shown. Result contain more records that are not displayed

Tags: birt, rcp

Hi I am creating a **BIRT** report inside eclipse. I want to show the report in **Eclipse RCP application.**  I am using java pojo as scripted data source. Now In the java script of the report, when I print output to console from open and fetch method and If I switch to preview results tab after double clicking on data set. It says 500 records are shown in the results and on console it prints ,don't know ow many times. I know it is related to fetch method looping n return value, but I am not sure exact reason.
here is my fetch method:

```
count = 0;


if(count < 3){
row["Temperature"] = outtemp;
System.out.println(outtemp);

row["Air"] = AList.get(0).getAirflow();
row["Power"] = AList.get(0).getPower(); 
row["Duct"] = AList.get(0).isDucted();
System.out.println(AList.get(0).getAirflow());
System.out.println(AList.get(0).getPower());
System.out.println(AList.get(0).Ducted());

row["CAirflow"] = CList.get(0).getAirflow();
row["CTemperature"] = CList.get(0).getTemp();
System.out.println(CList.get(0).getAirflow());
System.out.println(CList.get(0).getTemp());

row["Ratio"] = TList.get(0).getRatio();
System.out.println(TList.get(0).getRatio());

count++;

return true; 
}

return false;
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking, but by design in preview it only shows 500 records. Sometimes it will show less than 500, even if there should be more than 500 in the results.

Comment: Thanks James. Actually fetch was called infinitely.Since count = 0 is in fetch method, it was called for every single row i.e count starts over initializing to 0 again.hence I was getting 500 rows for the single row.